# NumPy tensordot grouped calculation

Tags: python, numpy, tensordot

suppose I have two arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2],
            [3,4]])

b=np.array([[1,2],
            [3,4]])
```

and I want to element-wise multiply the arrays then sum the elements, i.e. `1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4 = 30`, I can use:

```py
np.tensordot(a, b, axes=((-2,-1),(-2,-1)))
>>> array(30)
```

Now, suppose arrays `a` and `b` are 2-by-2-by-2 arrays:

```py
a=np.array([[[1, 2],
             [3, 4]],

            [[5, 6],
             [7, 8]]])

b=np.array([[[1, 2],
             [3, 4]],

            [[5, 6],
             [7, 8]]])
```

and I want to do the same operation for each group, i.e. `[[1,2],[3,4]]` times with `[[1,2],[3,4]]` then sums the elements, and the same with `[[5,6],[7,8]]`. The result should be `array([ 30, 174])`, where `30 = 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4` and `174 = 5*5 + 6*6 + 7*7 + 8*8`. Is there a way to do that using tensordot?

**P.S.**
I understand in this case you can simply use sum or einsum:

```py
np.sum(a*b,axis=(-2,-1))
>>> array([ 30, 174])

np.einsum('ijk,ijk->i',a,b)
>>> array([ 30, 174])
```

but this is merely a simplified example, I need to use `tensordot` because it's faster.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: use `matmul` with some argument reshaping

Comment: I don't see it as a matrix multiplication? It's just an element-wise multiplication then sum all elements.

Comment: What do you think the 'dot' in `tensordot` implies?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do the results match the documentation?  Have you read `matmul` docs yet?

Comment: `tensordot` does an 'outer' product on the leading dimensions; `matmul` uses the broadcasting rules, and treats them as a 'batch'.  `(a.reshape(2,1,4)@b.reshape(2,4,1)).squeeze()`

Comment: Hi @hpaulj thanks for you answer, yes matmul works in this case, sorry I simplified my question too much. I've opened another post better describe it, please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907083/numpy-einsum-tensordot-with-shared-non-contracted-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `np.diag(np.tensordot(a, b, axes=((1, 2), (1, 2))))` to get the result you want. However, using `np.tensordot` or a matrix multiplication is not a good idea in you case as they do much more work than needed. The fact that they are efficiently implemented does not balance the fact that they do much more computation than needed (only the diagonal is useful here). `np.einsum('ijk,ijk->i',a,b)` does not compute more things than needed in your case. You can try the `optimize=True` or even `optimize='optimal'` since the parameter `optimize` is set to `False` by default. If this is not fast enough, you can try to use NumExpr so to compute `np.sum(a*b,axis=(1, 2))` more efficiently (probably in parallel). Alternatively, you can use Numba or Cython too. Both supports fast parallel loops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried with `optimize` but it's still very slow.. I've opened another post better describes my question, please have a look, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907083/numpy-einsum-tensordot-with-shared-non-contracted-axis